# facebook registration plugin : populating custom fields

Tags: facebook, plugins, registration, custom-fields

I have an HTML form that uses the Facebook registration plugin. I have a couple of custom text fields (the kind that are included in the iFrame itself).

Whether user prefills the form using Facebook. or enters the data himself, I am able to  store all values in my database without.

At the end of my post method, I redirect to load the same page. At this point, I would like to populate the fields from the data in my database. By which I mean, if the user logs off Facebook, on this page, he should still see the data that he has submitted to my database.

How do I set values for the fields (both custom and regular fields) in the registration form?

Should I say `document.getElementById('field_name').value = "hello"`?

Comment: Which technology are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends which technology you are using to generate the pages.  That would be good to know. You most likely would have the JSP/ASP/PHP prepopulate those fields with from the data as it sends the HTML to the user.